# Ionic/AngularJS/Instafeed can't access scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, instafeedjs

My question is for Ionic. The following code added to my controller in AngularJS works in pure AngularJS.

In Ionic though, the same code snippet doesn't work. tagName remains undefined. And in this case, I cannot access the scope value. If I change the tagName to something like 'cat' it pulls instagram photos successfully.
Any thoughts on how to be able to access the scope?

Error: No tag name specified. Use the 'tagName' option.

```
  var feed = new Instafeed({
    get: 'tagged',
    tagName: $scope.artists.instagram,
    clientId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    resolution : 'standard_resolution'
  });

  feed.run();
```

Comment: are you sure you have `$scope.artists.instagram` has some value?

Comment: need more information. Can you give the injection block, routine to get there or something other than it works here, but not there?

Comment: yes, it pulls from a json file which has a value for instagram. $http.get('js/data.json').success(function(data) {
      $scope.artists = data;

Comment: So Instafeed.js works properly on my web version as seen here: http://jaggermoon.com/hhg2/#/barneys-chelsea but when I use the same code in Ionic, I can't get it to access $scope.artists.instagram it returns it as undefined: "Error: No tag name specified. User the 'tagName' option."

Answer (score 0):

For anyone coming across this problem, I've created a simple lightweight angular wrapper for Instafeed. You can find it with instructions and a demo which uses $scope variables bound via ngModel at https://github.com/zephinzer/ngInstafeed. Cheers!